# Is there a shortcut to switch between panes in the Eclipse Compare view?

Tags: eclipse

When I compare two versions of a source file (for example, from egit) in the Eclipse IDE, the Compare View is appeared. It has two panes containing two versions of a text and I can use keyboard to move cursor through the text on one of this panes (or even edit the text in it). Additionally, I can use special shortcuts to go to the next/previous difference and/or apply current change from/to the opposite pane. But, I didn't find a way to move the input focus to other pane.

Actually, I would like be able to do this in one case. Let's say, I compare two revisions of a source and I need to apply some changes while others are unneeded. To achieve this, I walk through changes using the `Ctrl` + `,` or `.` shortcuts and apply needed changes using, for example, the `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `,`. It looks like all is OK, but if I reach a change which has no any text in the current pane, the applying shortcut does not work. For example, the cursor is on the left pane. I went to the next difference and this difference is concluded in that the text was, for example, added in this line. So, the Compare View will show this added text on the right pane, will highlight it with the special rectangle while this rectangle on the left pane will have zero height and the cursor will be placed under this zero-sized rectangle. I.e., outside of it. So, I think, exactly this thing causes that the current change applying does not work. When I click on the opposite pane, inside of this change and then use the change applying shortcut, it works fine. So, I would like to switch to other plane via shortcut, not using mouse.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your root issue. Switching from the left to right pane is Ctrl+Tab, and Ctrl+Shift+Tab to switch back.

Comment: @howlger, thank you. You know, right after I posted my question, I found the way you specified. So, the stack overflow site is the right place to ask questions!.. ))

Comment: And watch out for pressing Ctrl+Tab while on the right pane, or Ctrl+Shift+Tab while on the left pane, as those will tab out of that view. Pressing the "correcting" key (Ctrl+Tab if you press Ctrl+Shift+Tab too many times, or Ctrl+Shift+Tab if you press Ctrl+Tab too many times) will bring you back in.